# Virtual network peering connection azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I have the following three virtual networks: - VNETa - VNETb - VNETc All the network traffic between the three virtual networks will be routed through VNET1a.
need to create the virtual networks, and then to ensure that all the Azure virtual machines can connect to other virtual machines by using their private IP address.

The solutions must NOT require any virtual gateways and must minimize the number of peerings. What should you do from the Azure portal before you configuring IP routing?

Comment: You need a gateway.

Answer (score 0):

You could make peering between VNETa and VNETb, peering between VNETa and VNETc. Without a virtual network gateway and without a separate peering connection between those spokes VNETb and VNETc, to make the [spoke connectivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/hub-spoke#spoke-connectivity), you need to deploy a [virtual appliance](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/solutions/network-appliances/) as the hub in the network VNETa, then make two UDRs in each spoke VNets VNETb and VNETc to route traffic from one spoke network to another spoke network via NVA. In this scenario, you must configure the peering connections to **allow forwarded traffic**. see the explanation [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/29195#issuecomment-484003437).

[image]

For more details of UDR configuration, you could refer to this blog about [Azure Networking - Hub-Spoke with NVA and Azure Firewall](https://www.itinsights.org/Azure-Networking-Hub-Spoke-with-NVA-and-Azure-Firewall/)

Answer (score 0):

The key to answering this question is to understand that the question is indicating that an IP routing solution will be configured after you have provisioned the necessary resources and configured appropriately: "...before you configure IP routing".

You do not need a gateway subnet or virtual gateways to implement a hub and spoke topology assuming that you are going to provision, for example, a VM with IP Forwarding enabled on the vNIC to act as a router.

1. Create your 3 subnets, in your example VNETa, VNETb and VNETc
2. From VNETa, create a peering with VNETb using the Resource Manager Deployment Model
3. Ensure "Allow forwarded traffic from VNETa to VNETb" is enabled
4. Repeat steps 2 & 3, substituting VNETb for VNETc

And that's it.  Now when you configure IP routing you will provision a router VM or some other Network Virtual Appliance (NVA) in the hub network and create a Route Table for later application to VNETb and VNETc specifying the router VM's internal IP as the next hop.

Jamie.